# Dependencies in Github Actions are not shared between jobs

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have split up my load into different jobs. Both the "Test" and "Lint" step depend on the "Setup" step. All use the same runner. Still there is an error:

`npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: nx@15.8.5`
on the Lint job, indicating that the dependency from the previous `npm ci` is not there. If I have all things in a single job it works.

This is my config:

```
jobs:
  Setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: nrwl/nx-set-shas@v3

      # This is not done by actions/checkout@v3 by default, didnt find an option to configure it there.
      - name: Setup --base dev branch for NX
        run: git fetch origin dev:dev

      # install just the root Monorepo dependencies
      - name: Install Monorepo dependencies
        run: npm ci

      # We need all the libs to execute the tests
      - name: Install all library dependencies
        run: npm run install:libs --parallel=3

      - name: Affected Apps - Setup
        # install just the affected apps and exclude all libs because they have already been installed.
        run: npx nx affected --base=$GITHUB_BASE_REF --target=setup  --parallel=3

  Lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: Setup
    steps:
      - name: Affected Apps - Lint
        run: npx nx affected --base=$GITHUB_BASE_REF --target=lint --parallel=3

      - name: Workspace - Lint
        run: |
          npx nx workspace-lint
          npx nx format:check --base=$GITHUB_BASE_REF

  Test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: Setup
    steps:
      - name: Affected Apps - Test
        run: npx nx affected --base=$GITHUB_BASE_REF --target=test --parallel=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are independent, as the documentations mentions:

> Jobs on GitHub-hosted runners start in a clean runner image and must download dependencies each time.

So in case you want to optimise your build time, you may want to [cache your node module dependencies](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#example-using-the-cache-action), for example you'd have a build job containing:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Cache node modules
    id: cache-npm
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    env:
      cache-name: cache-node-modules
    with:
      # npm cache files are stored in `~/.npm` on Linux/macOS
      path: ~/.npm
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
        ${{ runner.os }}-build-
        ${{ runner.os }}-

  - if: ${{ steps.cache-npm.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
    name: List the state of node modules
    continue-on-error: true
    run: npm list

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: npm ci
```

Then you have to call `actions/checkout` and `npm ci` in every job even if you have a dependency with `needs`.

Edit:

If you check your pipeline again with the idea that every job runs on a new clean runner image and that npm dependencies and nx builds can be cached, you'd see that there is no need for a a `Setup` job, what I would do instead is to make the `setup` steps in a composite action and call it in every job and let every job do its setup, that shall be quick if the dependencies are cached.

And in case that you have a complex setup, consider creating a docker container in your setup job, then [share it with other jobs](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/225#issuecomment-724865050).